# Code unexpectedly stops after changing folder in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I have a macro1 that when it detects a new email in a certain folder it triggers another macro2 that goes to that specific folder, download all attachments, delete all emails and then goes back to inbox.

Macro1 runs well and trigger macro2.

The problem is: macro2 only runs halfway. When It executes, it runs only until the part of the code that sets the active folder to the one I desire. After that, it stops. When I run macro2 again, immediately after it stops, it works and download/delete the attachment.

It looks to me it is a single fix but I can't figure it out.

1-Macro1: If I get a new email in folder "Relatorio", it will run macro2

2-Macro2 will turn "Relatorio" active

#### it stops here ### if I run again, it proceeds

3-Macro2 will download all emails and attachments

4-Macro2 will delete all emails

5-Macro2 will change active folder to inbox back again

Macro2:

```
Dim objOL As Object 'As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
Dim objAttachments As Object 'As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Object 'As Outlook.Selection
Dim objFolder As Object 'As Outlook.Folder

Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String

strFolderpath = "C:\Users\hopnere\Desktop\Dashboard\"

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Relatorio") 
Set objOL.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objFolder

### stops here ###
Set objMsg = objOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection


For Each objMsg In objFolder.Items

Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count 'check if there is an email with attachment
    MsgBox lngCount
    If lngCount > 0 Then


        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
        i = lngCount

            strFile = strFolderpath & "Backend.xls" 'attachment destiny folder

            ' saves attachment
            objAttachments.item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

            ' Delete attachment
            objAttachments.item(i).Delete
            ' delete email
            objMsg.Delete

        Next i

    End If

Next

Set objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 'setting inbox active
Set objOL.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objFolder


ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection`**

Represents a set of Outlook items object  currently selected in an Active explorer, That procedure is called only when a message is selected - Remove it.

**`Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`**

Also, there is no need to create a new Outlook Application instance in the Outlook VBA macro, Instead, you can use the Application property,

for example:

**`Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)`**

Comment: Thank you very much, Om3r! It works like a charm now!

Comment: @Hopner please remember to accept the answer, Thank you